# OutlinedBox for TextInputEditText - attribute android:style not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Can not get working OutlinedBox for TextInputEditText. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388926/outlinedbox-for-textinputedittext-is-not-working) on Stackoverflow but none of solutions don't work.

As soon as I add `android:style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"` to the code, the form disappears from preview and when I try do build apk appears this error:

```
Android resource linking failed
com.my.app-main-50:/layout/fragment_login.xml:32: error: attribute android:style not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

Putting just `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"`

does not work either

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CkRz.png)

**build.gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

**code:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#EAEAEA"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_src"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/t_logo"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/app_description"
        android:id="@+id/appTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageLogo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editLoginWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appTitle"
        android:hint="@string/login_hint"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:id="@+id/editLogin"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editPasswordWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editLoginWrapper"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:id="@+id/editPassword" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/signIn"
        style="?attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPasswordWrapper"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/button_background" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
        style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signIn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password"
        android:textColor="#918B8B"
        android:textColorHighlight="#DC6C6C"
        android:textColorLink="#5E5E5E" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Style inside of TextInputLayout:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/editLoginWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appTitle"
    android:hint="@string/login_hint"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
```

The app just crashes:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41 in com.app.app:layout/fragment_login: Binary XML file line #41 in com.app.app:layout/fragment_login: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41 in com.app.app:layout/fragment_login: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

**Line 41 is:**

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

Comment: Did you try Invalidate and Restart and rebuilding the project? Also the style you're setting to TextInputEditText is actually for the TextInputLayout. Try setting it in the TextInputLayout.

Comment: I tried it all. I just updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the style in the `TextInputLayout` not `TextInputEditText`

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

and add the theme to the root layout and your activity theme should be `MaterialComponents`

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
```

Comment: THIS IS BY FAR THE BEST ANSWER ! I was struggling since 2 days to put my custom style to textInputLayout . Old activity theme with Appcompat was the culprit. Changed to material and worked like a charm ! Thank you !